Stop a select few apps from being killed by Samsung's game booster?
when I launch a game in Samsung's gaming hub, I have an option to turn on priority mode, this closes other processes which speeds up the game, however, I have a few apps I would like to continue running in the background. Is there a way for example to make sure the game booster does not kill Automate and Tasker?
